# UIView hierarchy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am just curious if I have a webview, and I want to have another custom uiview set on top of it.

So basically I have a window, and I have two views:

|--View1--|
|--webView|

how can I set these views based on the window on hierarchy manner? So one view and lay on top of another view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the uiview on top of the webview.  Just set the frame for the otherview, and then add it.

```
otherView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, webView.frame.size.width, 50);
[webview addSubview:otherview];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `subviews` documentation in the `UIView` class: "The order of the subviews in the array reflects their visible order on the screen, with the view at index 0 being the back-most view."

Comment: Philip, Yes but here I want to have them both up front, just set aligned as stacks but both visible.

Comment: Not sure I understand....  If the front one is smaller, the back one will show around it.  If the front one has some transparency, the back one will show through it to one degree or another.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of currently added UIViews, there are some methods that you can use to control the hierarchy programatically, like that:

- addSubview:
- **bringSubviewToFront:**
- **sendSubviewToBack:**
- removeFromSuperview
- insertSubview:atIndex:
- insertSubview:aboveSubview:
- insertSubview:belowSubview:
- exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
- isDescendantOfView:

Put special attention on the methods in bold, seems that is exactly what are you looking for. Also look around apple UIView documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

See ya!.